# How to parse wrapped json object

Tags: json, go

some API endpoint may return successful result or error like this:

```
// ok
{
    "status": "ok",
    "payload": {
        "id": 10,
        "title": "Sample"
    },
    "request_id": "lx-VHr4OLm"
}
// error
{
    "status": "error",
    "payload": {
        "message": "internal error"
    },
    "trace_id": "lx-VHr4OLm"
}
```

I'm trying to find elegant way to parse with Go, something like this

```
.... some code
if status == "ok" {
    struct := AppStruct{} // AppStruct contains 2 fields: id and title
    _ := json.Unmarshall(payloadBody, &struct)
    return struct 
} else {
    errorStruct := ErrorStruct{} // contains 1 field for message.
    _ := json.Unmarshall(payloadBody, &errorStruct) 
    return nil, errors.New(errorStruct.Message)
}
```

My current code not works for success payload:

```
var result map[string]interface{}
jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &result)
if jsonErr != nil {
    return nil, jsonErr
}
if result["status"] == "error" {
    errorPayload := result["payload"].(map[string]string)
    return nil, errors.New(errorPayload["message"])
} else if result["status"] == "ok" {
    apiResponse := AppInfo{}
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(result["payload"].(string)), &apiResponse)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        return nil, jsonErr
    }
    return &apiResponse, nil
}
```

And I got runtime error on line `json.Unmarshal([]byte(result["payload"].(string)), &apiResponse)`

> http: panic serving [::1]:51091: interface conversion: interface {} is
>   map[string]interface {}, not string

Surely, I may have 2 structs: for success response and for error one but I assume it's too complicated way to solve my problem.

How to parse this JSON in elegant way?

Comment: Something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/jcLLepMWUyx (haven't tested it so there may be some typos)

Comment: Slurp it into a map[string]interface{}. Not elegant, but it works. But your code would be very fine if you used a json.RawMessage for the payload instead of a interface{}.

Comment: Thanks for idea about RawMessage. I made more generic solution: https://play.golang.com/p/sMwVmArW3wz

Comment: Do you really need two different struct? Seem that the structure of the response is the same: a status and a payload (with three fields: id, title and message) the difference is in the data. My two cents.

Comment: Matteo, currently I use only one endpoint from this API but I assume that I may have to use more endpoints in same way in future so I would like to have generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva for idea to use json.RawMessage

My final solution:

```
func parsePayload(response []byte, successPayload interface{}) error {
    var result map[string]json.RawMessage
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(response, &result)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        return jsonErr
    }
    var status string
    jsonErr = json.Unmarshal(result["status"], &status)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        return jsonErr
    }
    if status == "ok" {
        jsonErr = json.Unmarshal(result["payload"], &successPayload)
        if jsonErr != nil {
            return jsonErr
        }
        return nil
    } else if status == "error" {
        errorPayload := ErrorPayload{}
        jsonErr = json.Unmarshal(result["payload"], &errorPayload)
        if jsonErr != nil {
            return jsonErr
        }
        return errors.New(errorPayload.Message)
    }
    log.Printf("Unknown http result status: %s", status)
    return errors.New("internal error")
}

type ErrorPayload struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

//usage

type AppInfo struct {
    Id    int    `json:"app_id"`
    Title string `json:"app_title"`
}

body := ... // read body
appInfo := AppInfo{}
parseErr := parsePayload(body, &appInfo)
if parseErr != nil {
    return nil, parseErr
}
log.Printf("Parsed app %v", appInfo)
return &appInfo, nil
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure what the problem is. The standard `encoding/json` doesn't require the struct to match *all* fields in the JSON data. It's quite easy to handle this with a single, simple type:

```
type Payload struct {
    ID      int    `json:"id"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

type Response struct {
    Status  string  `json:"status"`
    ID      string  `json:"request_id"`
    TraceID string  `json:"trace_id"`
    Payload Payload `json:"payload"`
}
```

Then just unmarshal the response in the `Response` struct:

```
var resp Response
if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &resp); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Then you can simply check the `Status`  field, and work out what to do next. For example:

```
if resp.Status == "error" {
    return fmt.Errorf("invalid response: %s - %s", resp.TraceID, resp.Payload.Message)
}
// handle resp.Payload.ID and resp.Payload.Title fields
return nil
```

You could move those checks for the status field to receiver functions on the response object, depending on the complexity and your specific needs.

Perhaps it's worth using pointer fields for those fields that aren't set in the normal response, and tag them with the `omitempty` option:

```
type Payload struct {
    ID      int     `json:"id"`
    Title   string  `json:"title"`
    Message *string `json:"message,omitempty"`
}
type Response struct {
    Status  string  `json:"status"`
    ID      string  `json:"request_id"`
    TraceID *string `json:"trace_id,omitempty"`
    Payload Payload `json:"payload"`
}
```

With types like this, no longer have to rely on hard-coded string constants to check for errors. Instead, you can easily implement a more generic check like so:

```
func (r Response) IsError() bool {
    return (r.TraceID == nil) // will be set in case of an error response
}
```

---

#### Update

As you pointed out in the comments, the response body is actually substantially larger than the 2 fields in the example. Of course, copy-pasting the struct definitions, or writing mapping functions to map the `Payload` onto the type you already have is a bit pointless.

The answer here is: composition.

```
type Payload struct {
    AppStruct // embedded the AppStruct type
    Message   *string `json:"message"`
}
```

The `Response`  type stays as it is. If the response is successful, you can get the `AppStruct` directly from the response like so:

```
appStruct := resp.Payload.AppStruct
```

This works because the type is embedded. Note that there aren't any `json` tags there. The embedded struct, at least as far as the unmarshalling is concerned, is a part of the `Payload` struct. Therefore, all the exported fields in that type will be unmarshalled directly into the struct.

Comment: Proposed solution is good but I'll return to origin issue when second endpoint will appear, eg with user profile
```"status": "ok",
    "payload": {
        "userId": 10,
        "userName": "John Smith",
        "avatarUrl": "http://example.com/....",
        "email":"j.smith@example.com"
    },
    "request_id": "lx-VHr4OLm"
```
So I may re-use my ```parsePayload``` function instead of copy-paste Response struct

Comment: @Andrew That's not a great idea, let me update my answer to make a suggestion you should consider instead

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about embedded structures, thank you. But for two endpoints (app info, user info) I'll have AppResponse, AppPayload, UserResponse, UserPayload. And in case of changing common part (add some field to root response) I have to change all *Response. My solution doesn't requires to change multiple structures.